# Store data without Userinteraction

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I want to store network devices data through a Django model `Device` to my database.

**Workflow**

1. Host configuration needs to be setup by User inside a View (*Host Model*)
2. When the Host configuration is finished the Network should be scanned for devices (Device Model)
3. The data should be stored inside the DB

**Problem:**

The fuction `create_devices()` only is allowed to get called when the Host is configured, but `if Host.objects.values():` isnt working.

1. How is it possible to call the function `create_devices()` only if one Host Model exists?
2. Is it correct to use a view to store Dynamic and Static Data in to the DB without User interaction?

Models:

```
class Host(models.Model):
    hostname = models.CharField(default="noads", max_length=6)
    ipv4_address = models.GenericIPAddressField('IPv4')
    ipv4_subnet = models.GenericIPAddressField('IPv4')
    gateway = models.GenericIPAddressField('IPv4')

class Device(models.Model):
    hostname = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    mac_address = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    ipv4_address = models.GenericIPAddressField('IPv4')
```

**My View:**

```
from webapp.models import Host, Device
from django.views import View
from django.views.generic.detail import DetailView
import multiprocessing.dummy
import multiprocessing

def create_devices():
    """
    Creates DB entry of devices if they dont already exist

    :return: List of mulitple devices stored in objects
    :rtype: list ["Device", "Device", ...]
    """

    available_devices = get_available_devices_in_list()
    arp_table_of_all_hosts = get_arp_table_linux()
    dev_list = []
        
    for deviceip in available_devices:
        #If device already exists in DB continue
        if arp_table_of_all_hosts.get(deviceip):
            if arp_table_of_all_hosts[deviceip] in Device.objects.filter(mac_address = arp_table_of_all_hosts[deviceip]):
                continue
            else:
                devmac = arp_table_of_all_hosts[deviceip]
                devname = "unknown"         #socket.gethostbyaddr(deviceip)
                dev = Device(hostname=devname, mac_address=devmac, ipv4_address=deviceip)
                dev.save()
                dev_list.append(dev)
        
    return dev_list

class DeviceGetAll(DetailView):
    if Host.objects.values():
        create_devices()
        model = Device
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

Your view `DeviceGetAll` is not written correctly. The `if` condition needs to be placed in some of the methods of the view, not in the class definition.

I don't understand what exactly you are trying to do, so I cannot know in which method you need to add the code to, but you can look at the base code of `DetailView` and see if some of those methods are useful to you.
I don't even know, if the detail view is the best place to put code that creates instances of the same model; maybe it could also go after the creation of the host.

---

But if you want to use the `DetailView`, the you could for example override the method `get_object()` from the `SingleObjectMixin` (which is one of the parents of `DetailView`), the your code could look like this:

```
class DeviceGetAll(DetailView):
    model = Device

    def get_object(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if Host.objects.exists():
            create_devices()

        obj = super().get_object(*args, **kwargs)
        return obj
```

Also, you probably mean to use the [`.exists()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#exists) method in the if-condition instead of `.values()`.

Comment: Tanks alot! shame on me, exists() is what i needed. So its okay to scan the network inside a view, wirte it inside the db, and create a detail view of all devices in the same class? or is there a more convenient way?

Comment: @kadopsdong If you need the decives to be created as soon as one host exists, then I suggest adding that code in the `CreateView.form_valid()` of the `Host` model.

Comment: Perfect:) but there is no way to scan the network asnyc right? The only opertunity is with a Threadpool to do it fast.

Comment: @kadopsdong If you want async, you can look into [Celery](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/django/first-steps-with-django.html) or [django-background-tasks](https://django-background-tasks.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Comment: Hello, sadly its the same problem after removing the db... when i use exists it throws an error cause there is no host setup.